# Selected option keeps being highlighted in last UIVIEW

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have a UIVIEWCONTROLLER with a table view.
If I press a cell in the table view, it goes to the second UIVIEWCONTROLLER.
But if I use the navbar in the second UIVIEWCONTROLLER to go back to the first UIVIEWCONTROLLER my option is still selected in the table view.

How can I change this, when I go back one screen I want my option(that I chose before) NOT to be highlighted.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
```

in you UITableViewController

A Boolean value indicating if the controller clears the selection when the table appears.
The default value of this property is YES. When YES, the table view controller clears the table’s current selection when it receives a viewWillAppear: message. Setting this property to NO preserves the selection.